# Start an UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger at a certain time in iOS 10

Tags: ios, notifications

I want to start a repeatable UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger (alarm every 15 min) from a certain time. Let's say you have an UNCalendarNotificationTrigger set at 8:00 and from now on you want a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger every 15 min. 8:15, 8:30 etc.

Because there is a limit on how many user notifications an iOS can have at a certain time. I just want two notification where the first one is triggered by a UNCalendarNotificationTrigger and the second one triggered by a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger. Therefore I wouldn't need multiple UNNotifications and just use two. Is this achievable?